# Editing Child Entities on a View In Isolated Form Posts While Retaining Unique HTML Ids

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

**What I Need Help With**

I am looking for the ***best practice approach*** to handle editing of child entities on a view in separate isolated form posts while retaining unique HTML Ids between child entities.

For example, at the top of the view I want to be able to change low level details about an Order (i.e. Total, Shipping Method, Address, etc.).  This section will post to an Action that takes an `OrderViewModel`.

I then want to display a list of Shipments which can be edited individually, each with their own form posts that map to actions for the specific ViewModel types...in my case `ShipmentViewModel`.

I want to do the same for various other Child Entity properties that are on the `OrderViewModel` including `OrderItems`, `OrderPayments`, `OrderCoupons`, etc.

**Why?**

The purpose of doing this is so that I don't have to pass an entire hydrated Order with every form post, when changing small details about an Order.

**What Have I Tried?**

I currently have this working using one main View, `OrderEdit.cshtml`, which uses the partial `_OrderDetailEdit.cshtml` to display a form for order details.  It then uses a for loop to iterate over the Shipments, and calls out to `Html.EditorFor(m => m.Shipments[i])` to leverage my custom Editor Template for Shipments.

**The Problem**

The problem with this approach is that my Action method for editing Shipments is forced to take an `OrderViewModel`, not a `ShipmentModel`.  That is not ideal since it will always be hydrated with one and only one Shipment.  It smells bad to use `orderEditViewModel.Shipments[0]` in my action.

Prior to using Editor Templates, I simply had a Partial for editing Shipments, which allowed me to post my form to an Action with the ideal method signature.  The problem with this approach was that the HTML ids for each Shipment were identical, causing UI issues with the jQuery plugins I'm using.